# Samsung Galaxy Tab frozen on update via Kies and no longer working

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-kies, system-freeze

I connected my Samsung galaxy tab and was updating it using the Kies software. It then got onto a section about emergency recovery. I selected the device and then nothing really happened.

So I went back to Kies to try and use the tab and now it has frozen on a black screen showing the phone and PC connection with a yellow warning triangle in the middle!

Cant do hard re-set and isn't able to be recognized on computer!This is the first Android/Samsung I've ever had so step by step advice would be great!